# Update Last Row as First row Value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have table in  below format

```
SeqID Control_ID    Data_Value  RowNum

 1    SEARCH         SEARCH      3
 1    BROKERREF      BZ815       4
 1    SYSTEM          0          5
 2    pdp            pdp         1
 2    test           123         2
 2    system         235         3
```

I want to update the table to be in below format

```
SeqID Control_ID    Data_Value  RowNum

 1     BROKERREF      BZ815      4
 1     SYSTEM          0         5
 1     SEARCH         SEARCH     3
 2     test           123        2
 2     system         235        3 
 2     pdp            pdp        1
```

I need to select the top row as a last row for each group of sequence ID.

Note : Control_Id and DataValue Column name will be same for the row which need to be selected as a last row for each unique sequenceID

Thanks in advance.

Comment: In your updated table what is it changing except its sorting? And why you want to update your table ;).

Answer (score 0):

Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to locate the first row per `SeqID`. Then, in an outer query, use `CASE` expression in the `ORDER BY` clause to place this row in the last 
position within its partition:

```
SELECT SeqID, Control_ID, Data_Value, RowNum
FROM (
   SELECT SeqID, Control_ID, Data_Value, RowNum,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY SeqID ORDER BY RowNum) AS rn
   FROM mytable ) t
ORDER BY SeqID,
         CASE WHEN t.rn = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
         RowNum
```

[**SQL Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bd54e/2)